# Creating table with javascript and add id and class to each td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm trying to create a chess game in javascript. I created a chessboard and the next step is to add an id's and classes to created td's.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Play Chess! </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.scss' type='text/css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var table ='';
            var rows =8;
            var cols=8;
            for (var r = 0; r<rows;r++){
                table +='<tr>';
                    for(var c=0;c<cols;c++){
                        table+='<td>' +''+'</td>';
                    }
                table+='</tr>';
            }
            document.write("<table border=1>"+table+'</table>');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know I can simply do this with html, but it's too much code and I belive there is other way to do this.

Comment: Good job! Now what?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Make a comment if you are going to downvote, please.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with plain JavaScript (no jQuery). Put the script just before the closing `</body>` tag. This does not use `document.write` which really is to be avoided. Instead the HTML has an empty table with an `id` attribute, which then is populated through script.

```js
var rows =8;
var cols=8;
var table = document.getElementById('board');
for (var r = 0; r<rows; r++){
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var c = 0; c<cols; c++){
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.setAttribute('id', 'abcdefgh'.charAt(c) + (rows-r));
    cell.setAttribute('class', 'cell ' + ((c+r) % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'));
  }
}
```

```css
table { 
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.cell { width: 20px; height: 20px; }
.odd { background-color: brown }
.even { background-color: pink }
```

```html
<table id="board"></table>
```

As a bonus it has the chessboard altering colors, and the `id` values are running from `a1` (bottom-left) to `h8` (top-right)

Answer (score 0):

If you can solve this issue by coding the layout directly inside your HTML file, you should definitely do that instead of building it dynamically in JavaScript. This is hugely less error-prone.

That being said, solving this using jQuery is not too hard:

```js
var sideLength = 8;

var table = $('<table>');
$('#root').append(table);

for (var i = 0; i < sideLength; i++) {
  var row = $('<tr>');
  table.append(row);

  for (var j = 0; j < sideLength; j++) {
    row.append($('<td>'));
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```