# Drawing 5x5 chess board - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to draw a 5x5 chess board on a site, and I got the cells but they aren't starting on a new line every 5 cells...

code for drawing the board:

```
// Drawing the board
class Board {
        draw(el){
            let tile = "<div class='tile'>";

            for (let row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
                for (let col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
                    let cellType = tile;
                    el.innerHTML += cellType;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    let b = new Board();
    b.draw(document.getElementById("board"));
```

for the full code look on http://klaslokaalmaker.nl

Comment: The better way is to use tables

Comment: What are the styles associated with `class='tile'`? (Your question must be completely self-contained.)

Comment: Well you need some CSS for that. I'd advise CSS Grid, but it might be complicated for beginners. Take a hint from here: https://jsfiddle.net/ldong/o4bu6q5r/

Comment: Please avoid linking to code. Can you show, here, the css being used? It will greatly effect the board.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39110657/5459839) for a working example of a 8x8 chessboard. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53748510/5459839) is one that includes chess pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your style sheet such that the width and height are moved from divs to the tile class instead. Otherwise, you are setting the board to be of the tile size as well.

```
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
  background:#fff;
  color:#000;
  margin:0 -1px -1px 0;
}


div:hover {
  opacity:0.8;
}

.tile {
  background: #E7A56B; 
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
}
```

Add a new line break after each row to separate each row.

```
class Board {
  draw(el){
    let tile = "<div class='tile'/>";

    for (let row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        let cellType = tile;
        el.innerHTML += cellType;
      }
      el.innerHTML += "<br/>"
    }
  }
}

let b = new Board();
b.draw(document.getElementById("board"));
```